# Find nearest sum of numbers in array to a given number

Tags: php, combinations

Say I have an `array [10000,5000,1000,1000]` and I would like to find the closest sum of numbers to a given number. Sorry for the bad explanation but here's an example:

Say I have an `array [10000,5000,1000,1000]` I want to find the closest numbers to, say **6000**.

Then the method should return **5000 and 1000**

another example : we want the closest to **14000** , so then he should return **10000 and 5000**

here i've tried on php but it's something wrong when i put **6000** i should get **5000 and 1000**

```
<?php

$arr    = [10000,5000,1000,1000];
$x      = 6000;
var_dump(eek($x,$arr));

function eek($x,$arr)
{
    $index = [];
    $counter = 0;
    foreach($arr as $val)
    {
        if($counter + $val <= $x)
        {
            $counter += $val;
            $index[] = $val;
        }
        elseif($counter + $val >= $x)
        {
            $counter += $val;
            $index[] = $val;
            break;
        }
    }

    if($counter == $x)
    {
        return $index;
    }
    elseif($counter >= $x)
    {
        return $index;    
    }
    else
    {
        return [];
    }
}

?>
```

Anyone have solution about it ?

Comment: it's my problem on my job and i've stack for 2 days

Comment: @N69S his homework or not he has tried solving it has he not?

Comment: @user3532758, thanks dude for appreciate me ... he said like that maybe cause I have no reputation here and assuming that I am a student ...

Comment: there is even a PHP implementation: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-sorted-array-number-x-find-pair-array-whose-sum-closest-x/

Comment: Sounds like a wonderful training set for test-driven development. If something else is returned, what have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: @geldek Finding a pair is different from finding a subset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is works with float and negative values:

```
$numbers = array(
    10000,5000,1000,1000
);
$desiredSum = 6000;
$minDist = null;
$minDist_I = null;
// Iterate on every possible combination
$maxI = pow(2,sizeof($numbers));
for($i=0;$i<$maxI;$i++) {
    if(!(($i+1) % 1000)) echo ".";

    // Figure out which numbers to select in this 
    $sum = 0;
    for($j=0;$j<sizeof($numbers);$j++) {
        if($i & (1 << $j)) {
            $sum += $numbers[$j];
        }
    }
    $diff = abs($sum - $desiredSum);
    if($minDist_I === null || $diff < $minDist) {
        $minDist_I = $i;
        $minDist = $diff;
    }

    if($diff == 0) break;
}
$chosen = array();
for($j=0;$j<sizeof($numbers);$j++) {
    if($minDist_I & (1 << $j)) $chosen[] = $numbers[$j];
}
echo "\nThese numbers sum to " . array_sum($chosen)  . " (closest to $desiredSum): ";
echo implode(", ", $chosen);
echo "\n";
```

Comment: Welcome it will work even if it's full of negative float and non ordered values

Comment: sir, why when i try on big arrays why it's running very slow till php execution timeout ... do u have any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Taking in count that the array is ordered from bigger to smaller values

Here is a solution, starting from yours

```php
function eek($x,$arr)
{
    $index = [];
    $counter = 0;
    foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
        if($counter + $val < $x) {
            $counter += $val;
            $index[] = $val;
        } else {
            if (isset($arr[$key+1]) && (abs($counter + $arr[$key+1] -$x) < abs($counter + $val -$x))) {
                continue;
            } else {
                $index[] = $val;
                return $index;
            }
        }
    }

    return $index;
}
```

Comment: @Aaron keep in mind that it's not a perfect solution, i just optimized what you started with.