# Optimizing Find nearest sum of numbers in array to a given number

Tags: php, combinations

Say I have an array [10000,5000,1000,1000] and I would like to find the closest sum of numbers to a given number. Sorry for the bad explanation but here's an example:

Say I have an array [10000,5000,1000,1000] I want to find the closest numbers to, say 6000.

Then the method should return 5000 and 1000

another example : we want the closest to 14000 , so then he should return 10000 and 5000

I've tried with code below, here is working one but if the **$desiredSum** and **$numbers array** is big. it's running so slow until php execution timeout

```
$numbers = array(
    10000,5000,1000,1000
);
$desiredSum = 6000;
$minDist = null;
$minDist_I = null;
// Iterate on every possible combination
$maxI = pow(2,sizeof($numbers));
for($i=0;$i<$maxI;$i++) {
    if(!(($i+1) % 1000)) echo ".";

    // Figure out which numbers to select in this 
    $sum = 0;
    for($j=0;$j<sizeof($numbers);$j++) {
        if($i & (1 << $j)) {
            $sum += $numbers[$j];
        }
    }
    $diff = abs($sum - $desiredSum);
    if($minDist_I === null || $diff < $minDist) {
        $minDist_I = $i;
        $minDist = $diff;
    }

    if($diff == 0) break;
}
$chosen = array();
for($j=0;$j<sizeof($numbers);$j++) {
    if($minDist_I & (1 << $j)) $chosen[] = $numbers[$j];
}
echo "\nThese numbers sum to " . array_sum($chosen)  . " (closest to $desiredSum): ";
echo implode(", ", $chosen);
echo "\n";
```

Anyone can help me out ?

Comment: This looks like subset sum problem. How large can be the size of the array?

Comment: Isn't this from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58918556/find-nearest-sum-of-numbers-in-array-to-a-given-number which you asked before.

Comment: @NigelRen, ya.. i was asked before but this solution running slow on big arrays

Comment: Did you check the other solution to see how that performed?

Comment: @vivek_23 about 100++ elements .. cause when i implement on my project also so many rows on the database .. then i get the rows put into $numbers array there ... any idea sir ?

Comment: @NigelRen ya, i was checked the others solution but the second solution not running perfect like the first solution ..

Comment: I think the second solution relies on the order of the numbers, so perhaps `rsort($arr);` before calling the function.

Comment: @NigelRen ya, u're right ... the second solution must be descending order and not running perfect ..when the desiredSum = 250.000

and let's say numbers array like this : 

```[100000,100000,100000,100000,100000,100000,50000,50000,50000,50000,10000,10000,500,500,500,1000,1000]
```
I want to get 100000 (100k) = 2
and 50000 (50k) = 1

but the second solution give me result 100k = 3 , here is the bug

Comment: @Aaron There does exist a dynamic programming solution to find the answer in quadratic time, but looking at your input numbers, I am afraid it would take a lot of memory. Your solution is taking time because it checks for every subset which is exponential. Since the data is sorted, I think you could prune(throw away) certain sets once you come to know aren't going to get close.

Comment: @Aaron I feel this is a variant of subset sum problem, i.e, coin change. I will let you know if I get some hints.

Comment: @vivek_23 hey, your guess is right LoL , actually this problem is coin payment haha ... it's weird because my boss also want give the coin change to user ...

Comment: @Aaron Haha. In that case, why does your boss wants to pay more(because sometimes closest is exceeding the actual payment)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

function coinChange($numbers,$desiredSum){
    sort($numbers);
    $set = [];
    $set[0] = [];

    for($i = $numbers[0];$i <= $desiredSum;++$i){
        foreach($numbers as $index => $current_number){
            if($i >= $current_number && isset($set[$i - $current_number])){
                if(isset($set[$i - $current_number][$index])) continue;
                $set[$i] = $set[$i - $current_number];
                $set[$i][$index] = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if(count($set) === 0){
        return [0,[]];
    }

    if(isset($set[$desiredSum])){

        return [
            $desiredSum,
            formatResult($numbers,array_keys($set[$desiredSum]))
        ];
    }else{
        $keys = array_keys($set);
        $nearestSum = end($keys);
        $sum = 0;
        $rev_numbers = array_reverse($numbers);
        $result = [];
        foreach($rev_numbers as $number){
            $sum += $number;
            $result[] = $number;
            if($sum > $nearestSum && abs($nearestSum - $desiredSum) > abs($sum - $desiredSum)){
                $nearestSum = $sum;
                break;
            }else if($sum > $nearestSum && abs($nearestSum - $desiredSum) < abs($sum - $desiredSum)){
                $result = formatResult($numbers,array_keys($set[$nearestSum]));
                break;
            }
        }

        return [
            $nearestSum,
            $result
        ];
    }
}

function formatResult($numbers,$keys){
    $result = [];
    foreach($keys as $key) $result[] = $numbers[$key];
    return $result;
}

print_r(coinChange([10000,5000,1000,1000],14000));
print_r(coinChange([10000,5000,1000,1000],13000));
print_r(coinChange([100000,100000,100000,100000,100000,100000,50000,50000,50000,50000,10000,10000,500,500,500,1000,1000],250000));
print_r(coinChange([100000,100000,100000,100000,100000,100000,50000,50000,50000,50000,10000,10000,500,500,500,1000,1000],179999));
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/hBGeW

**Algorithm:**

- This is similar to [coin change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem) problem.
- We first sort the numbers.
- Now, we iterate from minimum number in the array to the desired sum.
- Inside it, we iterate through all elements in the array.
- Now, we can make `$i`(which is a sum) only **if we have made** sum `$i - $current_number`. If we have the previous one, then we add `$current_number` to our collection for sum `$i`.

**Two Scenarios:**

- If we can make the **exact sum**, then we return the result as is.
- If we can't, then are 2 possibilities:

  - We would already have nearest sum possible in our `$set` which would be the last entry. We keep them in a variable.
  - Now, the nearest sum could also be higher than the desired sum. So, we get the larger sum and check if it's nearer than nearest smallest sum and then compare both and return the result.

**Result format:**

Let's take the below sample output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 15000
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10000
            [1] => 5000
        )

)
```

It simply means that the first index is the nearest sum possible and array at 2nd index is all elements it took from `$numbers` to make that sum.

Comment: @Aaron Glad to help :) . But I request you to thoroughly test it with different inputs.

Comment: ya ya ... i tested it and working perfectly ^_^ ,but why i can vote up ur answer ?...

Comment: @Aaron Great. I hope it doesn't give you memory limit exceeded with large inputs and is decently fast enough.

Comment: @Aaron You can upvote only if your reputation is 15 or above. https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up Currently your repu is 5 but will grow as you keep contributing to SO.

Comment: oh sir .. i just found a bug if we put 900 which we have 100 = 8 and 1000 = 1 it's give us all of 100 (though the coin doesn't enough)  .. it should give us 1000 then we got the change 100 , here's the demo : https://3v4l.org/MtADk

Comment: @Aaron `800` and `1000` are equally nearest to `900`. Hence, it outputs `800` as the answer.

Comment: if i want to get the greater coin nearest with **900** , which in this case **1000** should we sort them to descending first ?

Comment: @Aaron Just a small change of `>` to `>=` on line number 38 in https://3v4l.org/MtADk . So it would look like `abs($nearestSum - $desiredSum) >= abs($sum - $desiredSum)`

Comment: after few weeks, I found a new bug that the array values are : 
`[500000, 10000, 10000, 5000, 1000, 100, 100, 100, 100]`

and the $desiredSum is = *55600* , it's still give me :
`
 (
            [0] => 10000
            [1] => 10000
            [2] => 5000
            [3] => 1000
            [4] => 100
            [5] => 100
            [6] => 100
            [7] => 100
)
`
it should be give me 500000 becuz our coins doesn't enough and 500000 is *biggest unit of our coins*
Here is the demo : https://3v4l.org/J2oFl
Any solutions please ?

Comment: @Aaron How is `500000` more nearest to `55600` than `26400`(which my answer gave) as you have asked for nearest sum in your question?

Comment: actually, the coins used for payment ,let say `55600` is the price, and `[500000, 10000, 10000, 5000, 1000, 100, 100, 100, 100]` is coins on our wallet, so user shouldn't paid lower than price ...

Comment: @Aaron Ok, but why will user pay such a high price?

Comment: @Aaron All you can do fix it is find a price in the array greater than 55600 in such cases. That will be your answer.

Comment: because system would be give the change to user

Comment: @Aaron Ok, now I understood the purpose of it. Let me fix it. Because the code was giving nearest sum as I didn't know the purpose.